# What is the formal way to load numpy package?

Tags: python, numpy

I was reading the official documentation of **Scipy** and **Numpy**,  and there they show the default way to use the import:

```
        >>> import numpy as np
```

But some times i see in codes and presentations people using this way to load Numpy package:

```
        >>> from numpy import *
```

I known that the second way to load this package simplifies some task, but as i said in my question, what is the formal way to do this? (although the documentation show the default way to do this) Or this is a personal taste?

Comment: There is no formal way. I prefer the former so it doesn't pollute the namespace. You can also introduce individual names into the namespace with `from numpy import ndarray`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm going to answer this instead of voting to close as opinion-based because of the following problem:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bool(any(x < 3 for x in [10,20,30]))
False
>>> from numpy import *
>>> bool(any(x < 3 for x in [10,20,30]))
True
```

`numpy` has its own functions, like `any` and `max` and `min` (these are just the ones that come to mind -- this is not meant to be exhaustive), which shadow built-ins.  The numpy versions don't play well with generator expressions, and they don't warn you that they don't.  Really what's happening in the above is that `np.any` is returning a generator, and the *generator itself* has a bool value of True-- which isn't what you want, you want the *result* of evaluating the generator.

```
>>> np.any(x < 3 for x in [10,20,30])
<generator object <genexpr> at 0xb3ba050c>
>>> bool(_)
True
```

Now to be fair, sometimes when I'm working interactively I *do* use a star-import -- but that's only for convenience during exploration, never in real code.

As a result, `import numpy as np` is far, far better than `from numpy import *` or `from pylab import *` or using any environment which does that, because unless you already know the dangers you're very likely to introduce a bug in your code.  You can always import specific functions directly (`from numpy import sin, cos` etc.), and sometimes that makes some formulae look prettier.

Comment: I usually use `IPython --pylab`, but with option that turns off the `*` import.  All code is clearer when module is identified.

Answer (score 1):

`import numpy as np` lets you call methods of numpy by saying `np.method()`. If you only use `import numpy`, you call methods of numpy by saying `numpy.method()`. If you use `from numpy import *` you can individually use the methods by calling `method()`, but rather than using *, you should just import the specific methods you need by saying `from numpy import method`, and you call methods by using `method()`. Personally, I suggest one of the first two methods (`import numpy as np` or `import numpy`)